# First Web App - Pig Game

Tags: javascript, beginner, game, html, css

I'm learning web development with JavaScript, HTML, and CSS and have just created my first application, a Pig Game. The app works well, however, I think my CSS is a bit over complicated and that the media query I wrote for responsiveness could be greatly improved.

Game rules:
Player 1 starts first. Each player take turns to roll a single dice as
many times as they wish, adding all roll results to a running total.
However if the player rolls a 1, they lose their gained score. Press
the hold button to stop rolling the dice. First player to 100 points
wins!

HTML:

```
<body>
<!-- Game Title  -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="game-title">
    <h1>PIG GAME</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="game-info-btns">
    <button type="button" class="new-game"> NEW GAME</button>
    <button type="button" class="how-btn">?</button>
  </div>

  <!--  How to Play Modal -->
  <div class="how-to-play hidden">
    <p>
      Player 1 starts first. Each player take turns to roll a single dice as
      many times as they wish, adding all roll results to a running total.
      However if the player rolls a 1, they lose their gained score. Press
      the hold button to stop rolling the dice. First player to 100 points
      wins!
    </p>
    <button class="close-how">Ok</button>
  </div>
  <div class="how-overlay hidden"></div>
  <!-- Main Game Window -->
  <div class="game-window">
    <!-- Player 1 -->
    <div class="p1-overlay overlay-active"></div>
    <div class="player1">
      <h1 class="player1-message">PLAYER 1</h1>
      <div class="score-wrapper">
        <span class="p1-score">0</span>
      </div>
      <div class="current">
        <p>CURRENT</p>
        <p><span class="p1-current-hold">0</span></p>
      </div>
      <div class="game-btn">
        <button type="button" class="p1-roll"> ROLL DICE</button>
        <button type="button" class="p1-hold"> HOLD</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dice hidden">
      <img src="images/dice1.png" id="diceImg" alt="dice" />
    </div>
    <!-- Player 2 -->
    <div class="p2-overlay show-me"></div>
    <div class="player2">
      <h1 class="player2-message">PLAYER 2</h1>
      <div class="score-wrapper">
        <span class="p2-score">0</span>
      </div>
      <div class="current">
        <p>CURRENT</p>
        <p><span class="p2-current-hold">0</span></p>
      </div>
      <div class="game-btn">
        <button type="button" class="p2-roll"> ROLL DICE</button>
        <button type="button" class="p2-hold"> HOLD</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

CSS:

```
    html {
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(to top left, #174e86, #97e4f4);
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
/* Game Info */

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: min-content min-content 1fr;
  align-content: center;
  justify-items: center;
}
.game-title {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}
.game-title h1 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: #eee;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}
.game-info-btns {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 2/3;
  margin-left: 44rem;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  display: flex;
}
.how-btn {
  margin-left: 1rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-color: #eee;
  background-color: rgba(191, 184, 191, 0.68);
  color: #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.new-game {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  width: 8rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  border-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.7rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background: #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* How to Play Modal */
.how-to-play {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 10rem;
  width: 28rem;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 2rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.7rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 2rem;
  border-color: #d3d3d3;
  z-index: 4;
}

.how-to-play p {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #000000;
}

.how-to-play button {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: #000000;
  float: right;
  background-color: rgba(236, 232, 236, 0.68);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.how-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  backdrop-filter: blur(3px);
  z-index: 3;
}

/* Main Game */
.game-window {
  grid-row: 3 / 4;
  position: relative;
  align-self: auto;
  width: 55rem;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  background-color: #e8749a;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: #eee;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.player1 {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 3rem 0;
}

.score-wrapper {
  font-size: 3rem;
}
.p1-overlay {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-top-left-radius: 0.5rem;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0.5rem;
  z-index: 1;
}
.player2 {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 3rem 0;
}

.p2-overlay {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-top-right-radius: 0.5rem;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0.5rem;
  z-index: 1;
}
.current {
  background-color: #d12e64;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  width: 15rem;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}
.current span {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.game-btn {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.game-btn button {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  width: 10rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.7rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-color: rgba(224, 218, 218, 0.5);
  background-color: rgba(191, 184, 184, 0.5);
  color: #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.p1-roll,
.p2-roll {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.dice {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  z-index: 2;
}

.dice img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

/* Hidden Class for Reuse */
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.overlay-active {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
}
.overlay-unactive {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

/* Media Query */

@media (max-width: 971px) {
  .container {
    position: relative;
  }
  .game-info-btns {
    margin-left: 57%;
  }
  .new-game {
    width: fit-content;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    padding: 0.4rem;
  }

  .game-window {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 2rem;
    width: 75%;
    margin: 3rem 2rem;
  }

  .player1 {
    grid-column: 1 / 1;
    grid-row: 1 / 2;
  }

  .p1-overlay {
    grid-column: 1 / 1;
    grid-row: 1 / 2;
    border-top-right-radius: 0.5rem;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0rem;
  }

  .player2 {
    grid-column: 1 / 1;
    grid-row: 2 / 3;
  }

  .p2-overlay {
    grid-column: 1 / 1;
    grid-row: 2 / 3;
    border-top-right-radius: 0rem;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0.5rem;
  }

  .dice {
    position: absolute;
    top: 51.5%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 4rem;
    height: 4rem;
    z-index: 2;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 770px) {
  .container {
    position: relative;
  }
  .game-info-btns {
    margin-left: 52%;
  }

  .dice {
    width: 3rem;
    height: 3rem;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 660px) {
  .game-title h1 {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
  .game-window {
    margin: 0rem;
  }
  .game-info-btns {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 1rem;
  }
  .how-to-play {
    width: 70%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .game-title h1 {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
  .game-window {
    margin: 0rem;
  }

  .player1 h1,
  .player2 h1 {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }

  .player1 span,
  .player2 span {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
  .game-btn button {
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    width: 8rem;
  }
  .current {
    width: 10rem;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
  }
  .current span {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }

  .game-info-btns {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
  }

  .new-game {
    font-size: 0.5rem;
  }

  .how-btn {
    height: 100%;
    align-self: end;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
  }

  .how-to-play {
    height: fit-content;
  }
}
```

Javascript:

```
  'use strict';

// Set DOM elements

// How to Play elements
const howBtn = document.querySelector('.how-btn');
const howWindow = document.querySelector('.how-to-play');
const howOverlay = document.querySelector('.how-overlay');
const closeHowBtn = document.querySelector('.close-how');
const newGameBtn = document.querySelector('.new-game');

// Gameplay Elements

//Player One Elements
const playerOneMessage = document.querySelector('.player1-message');
const playerOneOverlay = document.querySelector('.p1-overlay');
const playerOneScore = document.querySelector('.p1-score');
const playerOneCurrent = document.querySelector('.p1-current-hold');
const playerOneRoll = document.querySelector('.p1-roll');
const playerOneHold = document.querySelector('.p1-hold');

// Player Two Elements
const playerTwoMessage = document.querySelector('.player2-message');
const playerTwoOverlay = document.querySelector('.p2-overlay');
const playerTwoScore = document.querySelector('.p2-score');
const playerTwoCurrent = document.querySelector('.p2-current-hold');
const playerTwoRoll = document.querySelector('.p2-roll');
const playerTwoHold = document.querySelector('.p2-hold');

// Dice Elements
const diceBox = document.querySelector('.dice');
const dice = document.getElementById('diceImg');
const diceArr = [
  'images/dice1.png',
  'images/dice2.png',
  'images/dice3.png',
  'images/dice4.png',
  'images/dice5.png',
  'images/dice6.png',
];

// State Variables
let diceRoll = 0;
let score;
let current = 0;

// How to Play Modal
howBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
  removeHidden(howWindow);
  removeHidden(howOverlay);
});

howOverlay.addEventListener('click', function () {
  addHidden(howOverlay);
  addHidden(howWindow);
});

closeHowBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
  addHidden(howOverlay);
  addHidden(howWindow);
});

// Gameplay Logic

// Player 1 Rolls
playerOneRoll.addEventListener('click', function () {
  removeHidden(diceBox);
  diceRoll = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  changeDiceImg(`images/dice${diceRoll}.png`);
  current += diceRoll;
  playerOneCurrent.textContent = current;
  if (diceRoll === 1) playerTwoTurn();
});

playerOneHold.addEventListener('click', function () {
  score = Number(playerOneScore.textContent) + current;
  playerOneScore.textContent = score;
  console.log(score);
  if (score >= 100) {
    playerOneMessage.textContent = 'PLAYER 1 WINS! ';
    gameEnd();
  } else playerTwoTurn();
});

// Player 2 Rolls
playerTwoRoll.addEventListener('click', function () {
  diceRoll = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  changeDiceImg(`images/dice${diceRoll}.png`);
  current += diceRoll;
  playerTwoCurrent.textContent = current;
  if (diceRoll === 1) playerOneTurn();
});

playerTwoHold.addEventListener('click', function () {
  score = Number(playerTwoScore.textContent) + current;
  playerTwoScore.textContent = score;
  if (score >= 100) {
    playerTwoMessage.textContent = 'PLAYER 2 WINS! ';
    gameEnd();
  } else playerOneTurn();
});

// Reset values for New Game
newGameBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
  playerOneCurrent.textContent = 0;
  playerOneScore.textContent = 0;
  playerTwoCurrent.textContent = 0;
  playerTwoScore.textContent = 0;

  playerOneRoll.disabled = false;
  playerOneHold.disabled = false;
  playerTwoRoll.disabled = false;
  playerTwoHold.disabled = false;

  playerOneMessage.textContent = 'PLAYER 1';
  playerTwoMessage.textContent = 'PLAYER 2';

  addHidden(diceBox);
  playerOneTurn();
});

// Reusable functions
function addHidden(element) {
  element.classList.add('hidden');
}

function removeHidden(element) {
  element.classList.remove('hidden');
}

function changeDiceImg(source) {
  dice.src = source;
}

function playerOneTurn() {
  playerOneOverlay.classList.add('overlay-active');
  playerOneOverlay.classList.remove('overlay-unactive');

  playerTwoOverlay.classList.remove('overlay-active');
  playerTwoOverlay.classList.add('overlay-unactive');
  current = 0;
  playerTwoCurrent.textContent = current;
}

function playerTwoTurn() {
  playerTwoOverlay.classList.add('overlay-active');
  playerTwoOverlay.classList.remove('overlay-unactive');

  playerOneOverlay.classList.remove('overlay-active');
  playerOneOverlay.classList.add('overlay-unactive');
  current = 0;
  playerOneCurrent.textContent = current;
}

function gameEnd() {
  current = 0;
  addHidden(diceBox);
  playerOneRoll.disabled = true;
  playerOneHold.disabled = true;
  playerOneCurrent.textContent = current;

  playerTwoRoll.disabled = true;
  playerTwoHold.disabled = true;
  playerTwoCurrent.textContent = current;
}
```

If anyone could review the overall quality of the code in all three files, that'd be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

In your JavaScript code you might want to try storing your variables in an object, like so:

````
const howBtn = document.querySelector('.how-btn');
const howWindow = document.querySelector('.how-to-play');
const howOverlay = document.querySelector('.how-overlay');
const closeHowBtn = document.querySelector('.close-how');
const newGameBtn = document.querySelector('.new-game');
``` ==
``` const howToElements = {
howBtn:document.querySelector('.how-btn'),
howWindow:document.querySelector('.how-to-play'), 
howOverlay:document.querySelector('.how-overlay'), 
closeHowBtn:document.querySelector('.close-how'),
newGameBtn = document.querySelector('.new-game')
};
````

You can then access these variables using
`howToElements.howBtn`
and similar methods.

This alone should greatly improve the readability of your code.

In your CSS code you have some repeating rules in your CSS; instead try to [combine repeating rules](https://www.thoughtco.com/comma-in-css-selectors-3467052) into one.

I hope this helps.

Comment: The link to the article explaining the Comma Role in CSS is very helpful, nice!

Comment: Storing the variables is a great idea. The link was also very helpful, thank you!